# how to export multiple layers in single click to other folder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, advanced-license-level

i have more then 100 layers which need to exported to another folder for further analysis is there any way i can do that in a single click.  I tried to use package map but it says georeferencing error. i want to export then as "use same coordinate system as data frame".

the next thing is, this the topographical map data of 100 sheet which obviously have same name as transportation , river, land use etc ., i do tried to make a personal data base through the command "FeatureClass To Geodatabase (multiple) " the personal data base was created as topo 1 topo 2 but they all have same feature information one is replacing all 99 ie river 1 to river 99 have same data of river 1 
now suggest me what to do

Comment: You can do just about anything in one click with enough scripting, but this task doesn't seem ideal for a one-click solution.  You also appear to be asking two questions in a single Question, which is against practice here.